# django ORM - subqueries with Max

Tags: python, django, postgresql, subquery, django-orm

I'm having some issues when trying to use the Django ORM with subqueries and the Max function (db: PostgreSQL 15)

On the following model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    declaration = models.ForeignKey(
        Declaration,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="tasks",
    )
    sequence = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    #
    # other fields
```

***I'm trying to filter tasks related to a declaration with the highest sequence***.
here's my attempt:

```
sequences = Task.objects.filter(declaration=OuterRef("declaration")).exclude(sequence__isnull=True).order_by("sequence").distinct().values("sequence")
max_sequences = sequences.annotate(max_seq=Max("sequence")).values("max_seq")
qs = Task.objects.filter(sequence=Subquery(max_sequences))
```

however iterating the qs throws this error:

```
ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

inspecting the SQL, looks like this:

```
SELECT "task"."id",
       "task"."declaration_id",
       "task"."sequence"
FROM "task"
WHERE "task"."sequence" = (
    SELECT "subquery"."max_seq"
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(U0."sequence") AS "max_seq", U0."sequence"
            FROM "task" U0
            WHERE (U0."declaration_id" = ("task"."declaration_id") AND
            NOT (U0."sequence" IS NULL))
    GROUP BY U0."sequence"
    ORDER BY U0."sequence" ASC) subquery)
```

and the execution gives back the same error.

Adding `LIMIT 1` to the first subquery solves it on the db shell:

```
SELECT "task"."id",
       "task"."declaration_id",
       "task"."sequence"
FROM "task"
WHERE "task"."sequence" = (
    SELECT "subquery"."max_seq"
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(U0."sequence") AS "max_seq", U0."sequence"
            FROM "task" U0
            WHERE (U0."declaration_id" = ("task"."declaration_id") AND
            NOT (U0."sequence" IS NULL))
    GROUP BY U0."sequence"
    ORDER BY U0."sequence" ASC LIMIT 1) subquery)`
```

but I don't know how to do that with the Django queryset.
any help on this?

Thanks

Comment: `.values("max_seq")[:1]`.

Comment: BUt perhaps more important: *what* are you trying to achieve? This might be easier without a subquery

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike what I said earlier:
“I'm trying to filter tasks related to a declaration with the highest sequence“